# can't change pycharm sql dialect color

Tags: pycharm

I have some string SQL stuff in some variables, how can I change the background color that pycharm is adding to my SQL dialect (annoying yellow)

I check in the settings I wasn't able to find anything related to SQL background

```py
current_rep_query = "select  * from Customers where %s = ?"
```

something like this will have a yellow background

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can change all foreground and background related colors for SQL in `Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> SQL`.

You can click either on elements in the list, or on elements in the preview. To the right side of the window, you can tick or untick the boxes `Foreground` and/or `Background` and choose the colors you want.

This is valid for at least PyCharm Pro 2019.

Answer (score 0):

To just change the color and keep language injection: `Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> General -> Code -> Injected language fragment`. And from there deselect or change the background.

To disable SQL select/delete/insert/update/create language injection altogether: `Settings -> Editor -> Language Injections`. And from there deselect `python: "SQL select/delete/insert/update/create"`.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue occasionally re-occur after a JetBrain's update reverted my prior settings.  Your post inspired me to deep-dive into solving this.  Here's what I found:

**The Cause:**
The yellow background is actually PyCharm highlighting the entire SQL block with an inspection warning.

Disabling PyCharm's Language Injection for `python: SQL` prevents PyCharm from inspecting the SQL which is why it's a common solution.  However, this prevents PyCharm from applying formatting/color schemes to the SQL.

**How to Prevent the Highlighting:**
Fixing whatever is triggering the SQL warning will remove the highlighting.
You can do this by one of the following ways:

- Fixing the SQL issue (probably the preferred way)
- OR tell PyCharm to ignore the warning via `Settings > Editor > Inspections > SQL`

**How to Change or Disable the Background Color:**
If you just want to remove or change the color of the warning block, you can do so by:

- Open PyCharm settings
- Go to: `Color Scheme > General > Errors and Warnings > Warning`
- Disable or change the background color

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and I have just solved it. Head to `File -> Settings`, and within Settings, go to `Editor -> Inspections`. In the top search bar, search for "No data source configured". From here, you can change how you want pycharm to treat this inspection. You can change the severity to "No highlighting" to remove highlights altogether.

[Settings Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zc3BU.png)

Answer (score -1):

`Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> General`

Look for `Injected language fragment`

Comment: Please add more information to your answer

Comment: If there's something you don't understand in my answer - please state the exact part clearly, and I will gladly elaborate on it